# Why does a class print the object if only one statement is ran?

Tags: python, class

With the following class:

```
  class Test:
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test
        self.function()

    def function(self):
        print(self.test)
```

If I execute only this class

```
Test('test')
```

The output is as follows:

```
test
<__main__.Test object at 0x0000029A2515A978>
```

If I execute multiple lines of code:

```
print('print something first')
Test('test')
```

The object is not printed:

```
print something first
test
```

How come? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're executing these lines in an interactive interpreter, then the interpreter may show you the return value of a statement that you execute. That's just for your convenience: if you want to print something, use `print`.

Comment: I understand that. But why does it output  <__main__.Test object at 0x0000029A2515A978> I am not requesting for this to be printed

Comment: Because it is the value of the expression `Test('test')` that you executed.

Comment: You are trying to print the object stored in a memory location, if you directly use `print()` with the object name as arguement you will get the memory location

Comment: Allright. So the structure of my class is okay then I assume? Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: `<__main__.Test object at 0x0000029A2515A978>` is what a class instance looks like if you don't give it a `__repr__` method.